# tablet mode: prevent app from being maximized

Tags: windows, delphi, tablet

I have the problem, that I want to include one app into another.

In normal mode this works with no problem. In *Delphi (VCL)* I remove the window frame and set the container panel of the main app A as parent of the app B.

```
using WinApi.Windows;
var
  A: TPanel;
  B: TWinProcInfo;

SetParent(B.HWND, A.Handle);

// remove title bar and window frame
aWindowStyle := GetWindowLong(B.HWND, GWL_STYLE);
SetWindowLong(B.HWND, GWL_STYLE, aWindowStyle and (not WS_CAPTION) and (not WS_THICKFRAME));

// set position/size inside A
SetWindowPos(B.HWND, 0, 0, 0, A.width, A.height, SWP_NOSIZE)
```

Unfortunately, in tablet mode nevertheless the app B is displayed  maximized and now I also cannot get to the main app A, because it is the parent of B (so B overlays A).

But: not every app is maximized in tablet mode!

If I set `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := False;` in a Delphi demo app, that app can be freely moved and sized, even in tablet mode. If I understand the [docs](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.MainFormOnTaskBar) correctly this sets which form is connected to the taskbar icon.

> If the MainFormOnTaskBar is True, a taskbar button represents the application's main form and displays its caption. If False, a taskbar button represents the application's (hidden) main window and bears the application's Title.
> MainFormOnTaskBar must be True to use Windows Vista or Windows 7 Aero effects, including live taskbar thumbnails, Dynamic Windows, Windows Flip, and Windows Flip 3D.

**My problem now is:**
how can I do this for an external app? Because B is not my own (its UltraVNC btw).

Is there any winapi like the styling above to accomplish this?

Comment: To _restore_ a window from its _maximized_ state use [`ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_RESTORE )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow).

Comment: @AmigoJack No, this is not the case in tablet mode.